# Metric in a group with order divisible by 3

Tags: general-topology, finite-groups

Let $G$ be the non-abelian finite group whose order is divisible by $3$. Prove that exist a left invariant but not right invariant metric on $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that answering another your quention about [Metric on a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370552/metric-on-a-group/371038#371038), I have proved that $|G|$ is a power of 2 (see the line after Lemma 1).

Comment: It's best if you put the link in this answer (not just the comment), summarize the result in the link (_i.e._ the line after Lemma 1 seems to be the relevant point), and say why it implies the desired result asked about here.