# Example of a finite, non-abelian group in which left invariant metric is also right invariant

Tags: topological-groups

I need an example of a finite, non-abelian group $(G, \cdot)$ which satisfies the following condition:

If $d$ is a metric on $G$ such that $d(ax, ay)=d(x,y), \ \ \ \ \forall a,x,y \in G$,

then $d(xa, ya)=d(x,y), \ \ \ \ \forall a,x,y \in G$.

Could you help me find it or maybe tell me where to look for it?

Thank you.

Comment: Your title does not match the question, which asks for a non-abelian group on which every left invariant metric is also right invariant.

Comment: Ok, I've already changed it.

Comment: I am working with topological groups fifteen years and never heard this question before. But now I read it twice during the last two weeks. :-) (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370552/metric-on-a-group))